# Concatenating String Splits list into Parts?

Tags: python, list

```
x = 28
s = 1000
combo_list = []
while x != s:
  x= x + 3
  combo_list.append(x)

print(combo_list)

combo_string=str(combo_list)


y = "='Step 2 - Bench Sheets'!X'" 

for item in combo_string:
    output = y + str(item)
    print(output)
```

What this code should output is something along the lines of "='Step 2 - Bench Sheets'!X31'", but instead it outputs it into a weird split:

```
='Step 2 - Bench Sheets'!X'[
='Step 2 - Bench Sheets'!X'3
='Step 2 - Bench Sheets'!X'1
='Step 2 - Bench Sheets'!X',
='Step 2 - Bench Sheets'!X'
```

I'm trying to essentially make a code for an excel project at work that has some broken formatting. So I'm trying to speed it up a bit. I haven't been able to find anything online for this specific issue of a list splitting up the concatenation?? So if someone could help, that would be amazing. Thanks!

I've tried a few different things:

```
#for num in combo_string:
#    combo = y + str(combo_string)
#    string_list.append(combo)
```

This resulted in the same as above.

```
#for num in combo_string:
#    combo = y + str(num)
#    string_list.append(combo)
```

Same as above. But I think you get the picture by now. Just for some reason it's throwing a fit and I think I'm going about this the wrong way.

Comment: You convert the list to a string and iterate over it which means to iterate character by character.

Comment: because you did `combo_string=str(combo_list)`. Just remove that line, and use `combo_list` in your loop. `for item in combo_list: ... `

Answer (score 2):

Much simpler to use string formatting. You were also appending before your closed single quotes.

```
for x in range(31, 1001, 3):
    output = f"='Step 2 - Bench Sheets'!X{x}'"
    print(output)
```